# Как обратиться к дочернему объекту через родительский?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть родительский и дочерний объект. Как обратиться к дочернему через родительский, например вывести на экран значение из компонента дочернего, зная только родительский.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Через Transform

> **GetChild** -    Returns a transform child by index.
>
> **Find** -    Finds a child by name and returns it.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html

---

Из комментария:

```
GameObject Child = map [X, Y].gameObject.transform.Find("ChildName").gameObject;
```

Comment: GameObject Child = map [X, Y].GameObject.transform.child;

пытался таким образом, но выдает ошибку "Type `LoadGame' does not contain a definition for `GameObject' and no extension method `GameObject' of type `LoadGame' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Comment: Я ничего не понял, код без контектса.   Запись" map [X, Y].GameObject.transform.child" выглядит очень страно.  Что такое GameObject? может gameObject и у "transform" нет свойства "child"

Comment: @ Вадим Мороз , Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо, никак не мог с этим разобраться

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно получить ссылку на все дочерние объекты то сделать это можно непосредственно из родительского `Transform` который хранит всю информацию об иерархии вложенных объектов. При помощи [childCount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-childCount.html) можно узнать количество детей, а при помощи [hierarchyCount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hierarchyCount.html) количество всех объектов вложенной иерархии.
Зная количество потомков вы можете перебором получить доступ к любому из них посредством функции [GetChild](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html).

```
for (i = 0; i < transform.ChildCount; i++) {
         Tranform child = transform.GetChild(i)
         child.position += Vector3.up * 10.0F;
    }
```

Поиск через Find может оказаться более ресурсоемким, поэтому его не рекомендуется использовать в `Update` или `FixedUpdate`.
К тому же можно просто перебрать все вложенные элементы просто через энумератор Transform:

```
foreach (Transform child in transform) {
        child.position += Vector3.up * 10.0F;
    }
```

Еще один вариант это если вы собираетесь работать с информацией в компонентах детей найти их все скажем на `Start` и сохранить на них ссылки чтобы работать с ними напрямую (в том случае если иерархия объектов в сцене не изменяется). Найти вложенные компоненты можно при помощи метода [GetComponentsInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html) которая вернет вам все компоненты у родителя и детей вашего `Transform` по заданному типу в виде массива ссылок.